# Elaborate the recursion logic of the function, calling multiple times in javascript

Tags: javascript

i can't understand the recursive code of the code

```js
function logic(n, a, b) {
  if (n === 1) return;
  logic(n - 1, b, a);
  console.log(a);
  logic(n - 1, b, a);
}
logic(5, 'key', 'logger');
```

Why is the result this:

```
logger
key
logger
logger
logger
key
logger
key
logger
key
logger
logger
logger
key
logger
```

I can't understand.

Comment: By far the best way to understand the recursion logic here is to step through it with the debugger built into your IDE or browser.

Comment: how to do that ???

Comment: what is the practical use of it? i think the main problem is to understand the the forking into two recursions for every call, except if the exit condition is met. for any recursions, you could add another variable `level` which shows the depth of the resursion in a first step.

Comment: See the relevant page: [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/). Again, your IDE probably has a debugger built in too, look for a Debug menu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a small graphic can help you. The function displays now the entry on to, the middle, between the two calls and the end of the function. It has an indention for each further level and shows the side, meaning if the firts or second call in the resursion.

The pattern for every call is

```
start
             / recursion to left, swap key/logger
key/logger  *                    
             \ recursion to right, swap key/logger
end
```

```js
function log(...a) {
    out.innerHTML += a.join(' ') + '\n';
}

function logic(n, a, b, level = 0, side = '') {
    log(''.padStart(level * 4), level, 'start', side);
    if (n === 1) return;
    logic(n - 1, b, a, level + 1, side + 'l');
    log(''.padStart(level * 4), level, side, a);
    logic(n - 1, b, a, level + 1, side + 'r');
    log(''.padStart(level * 4), level, 'end', side);
}

logic(5, 'key', 'logger');
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```